# implicit super constructor Person() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor?

Tags: java, class, constructor, superclass

I am working on a project and i am getting the error "implicit super constructor Person() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor" and i don't quite understand it.

Here is my person class:

```
public class Person {
    public Person(String name, double DOB){

    }
}
```

And my student class when trying to implement the person class, and giving it an instructor variable.

```
public class Student extends Person {

    public Student(String Instructor) {

    }

}
```

Comment: try `super("Name", dob);` in `public Student(String instructor)`'s first line

Comment: How does the student know what its name and DOB is if you don't call an appropriate super constructor

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor,
> the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument
> constructor of the superclass.

If the super class does not have a

> no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object
> does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass,
> there is no problem.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html :
(See under section 'SubClass Constructors')

So whenever dealing with parameterized constructors make a  `super(parameter1, parameter2 ..)` call to the parent constructor.
**Also this super() call should be the FIRST line in your constructor block.**

Or else, if a scenario demands, create an additional non-parameterized () constructor in the parent class

Answer (score 12):

You need to make a `super` call to your defined constructor:

```
public Student(String instructor) {
    super(/* name */, /* date of birth */);
}
```

You can't just call `super()` because that constructor is not defined.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I achieved it (in my case the superclass was Team and the subclass was Scorer):

```
// Team.java
public class Team {
    String team;
    int won;
    int drawn;
    int lost;
    int goalsFor;
    int goalsAgainst;
    Team(String team, int won, int drawn, int lost, int goalsFor, int goalsAgainst){
        this.team = team;
        this.won = won;
        this.drawn = drawn;
        this.lost = lost;
        this.goalsFor = goalsFor;
        this.goalsAgainst = goalsAgainst;
    }
    int matchesPlayed(){
        return won + drawn + lost;
    }
    int goalDifference(){
        return goalsFor - goalsAgainst;
    }
    int points(){
        return (won * 3) + (drawn * 1);
    }
}
// Scorer.java
public class Scorer extends Team{
    String player;
    int goalsScored;
    Scorer(String player, int goalsScored, String team, int won, int drawn, int lost, int goalsFor, int goalsAgainst){
        super(team, won, drawn, lost, goalsFor, goalsAgainst);
        this.player = player;
        this.goalsScored = goalsScored;
    }
    float contribution(){
        return (float)this.goalsScored / (float)this.goalsFor;
    }
    float goalsPerMatch(){
        return (float)this.goalsScored/(float)(this.won + this.drawn + this.lost);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating a subclass constructor, if you don't explicitly call a superclass constructor with `super`, then Java will insert an implicit call to the no-arg "default" superclass constructor, i.e. `super();`.

However, your superclass `Person` doesn't have a no-arg constructor.  Either supply an explicit no-arg constructor in `Person` or explicitly call the existing superclass constructor in the `Student` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you can't create an instance without calling a constructor of its super class. And the jvm doesn't know how to call Person(String, double) from your Student(String) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this problem that you can **instantiate a
no-argument constructor at super class**.